# Split cells and insert in a new row

Tags: excel, vba

My data includes headers. In column C, the cells sometimes contain "/" or ",". The goal is to split these cells and insert a new row underneath with every sub-string.

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP7JH.png)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpoE2.png)

With the code below I have been able to replace all "," with "/". Split the cell in column C by the "/" delimiter and paste underneath. I have not been able to copy and paste the contents of the row underneath with every element in the split function array. It also seems to be pasting the split values beginning in cell C2 every time.

```
    Sub SuspenseReport()
        Dim SearchCell As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim cell As Range
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set Rng = Application.Range("C2:C1000") '*Change Last Row Value Here
        vLr = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

        For Each cell In Rng
        cell = Replace(cell, ",", "/")

        If InStr(1, cell, "/") <> 0 Then
        SearchCell = Split(cell, "/")
        For i = 0 To UBound(SearchCell)

        Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = SearchCell(i)
        Next i
        End If

        Next cell

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting or deleting rows always work from the bottom up. To retain the order of the split value, work from last to first.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitSlash()
    Dim tmp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Columns("C").Replace what:=Chr(44), replacement:=Chr(47), lookat:=xlPart
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            tmp = Split(.Cells(i, "C").Value2 & Chr(47), Chr(47))
            For j = UBound(tmp) - 1 To LBound(tmp) + 1 Step -1
                .Cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i + 1, "A") = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
                .Cells(i + 1, "B") = .Cells(i, "B").Value2
                .Cells(i + 1, "C") = tmp(j)
            Next j
            .Cells(i, "C") = tmp(j)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```